# How to run an applet with you webpage?

Tags: java, html, applet

I have checked to make sure my Java is up-to-date and enabled. I ran the command java -showversion in cmd, output:

java version "1.8.0_65"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

And to check if enabled, I am using Internet Explorer, went to Tools --> Internet Options --> Security Tab --> Custom Level --> Scripting Of Java Applets --> Enabled

The applet will not run. . . I am new to Java, any help would be appreciated.

Simple HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
 <title>Applet</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <APPLET CODE="http://www.example.com/dir/applet.class" width=400 height=400></APPLET> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Java Code:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;

 public class javaClass extends JApplet {

     public void init()
     {
         JLabel label = new JLabel("My Example label.!?");
         setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         add(label);
     }

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'will not run'?

Comment: Nothing happens. When my html loads the applet should then load and a window with the title javaClass and outputting the text My Example Label, with the dimensions width=400 height=400 should appear in the web browser/website, it doesn't seem to be taking place.

Comment: After I correctly set my environmental variables. .  using the appletviewer via command-line interface works perfectly. Props @Graystripe

Comment: Why was I given a minus-tick? I researched and found nothing on this particular issue that seemed to help. I gave a thorough explanation to what my problem was, provided my code as well. This giving anyone willing to help the proper foundation to reconstruct my issue. This way will also help anyone else with the same issue. They might be able to relate by looking at my code, where I went to enable Java and the commands to check whether I had the correct versions. I am fairly new but I try to follow the guidelines every-time I post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applet code (in the `<body>`) is attempting to access the applet class in the dir directory in example.com, which I would presume is incorrect.

What you would want instead, assuming that the HTML file is in the same directory as the `javaClass` is the following as the `<body>`:

```
<body>
<APPLET CODE = "javaClass.class" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=400></APPLET>
</body>
```

The reason this works is because the string after `CODE =` looks for the compiled class *within the same directory* of the corresponding Java source code. This means that you need to compile `javaClass` before it can be run as an applet: either within an IDE (such as NetBeans, Eclipse, or IntelliJ) or by using the `javac` command.

Then to actually view the applet, open the HTML file in your browser.

(Personally, I would use this cmd command: `appletviewer javaClass.html` instead of opening it in the browser (assuming the html file is called `javaClass`))

Comment: After correcting my environment variables using the command appletviewer via command-line interface worked beautiful.                        x++ & checked you

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` means HTML5, doesn't it? The applet tag isn't present in HTML5. Use `<embed>` or `<object>` instead.

An example showing how to embed applets in HTML5:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
  <param name="code" value="Sample" />
  <param name="archive" value="Sample.jar" />
  Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```

However, you might be best to steer away from applets toward [webstart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/), as applets are being disabled in the latest browsers (from click-to-run to totally disabled, I believe).